# How can change "copy link address" url in browser context menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change **copy link address** URL in browser context menu when user clicking on it. for example, I have 2 URL for a link and I need give user separate link when he copying the URL by **copy link address**

do it have event in javascrip?
[image]

Comment: No, you do not.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: you can't do using JS...

Comment: You can modify URL on contextmenu event and revert it back if needed on next anchor `mousedown/keydown` but your question is missing your exact expected behaviour, so?!

Comment: You may take a look to WebExtensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/onClicked

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by doing something like this

```
<a href="http://linkwhencopied.com" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://linkwhenclicked.com'">Funky link</a>
```

Comment: there is no need for `javascript:` in the onclick

Comment: This is the best way of handling it. Google does something similar by changing the url on mousedown, inspect the link and you see they change the url.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is no event for copying the link, but you still have the event for right click!

Since you tagged your questions as jQuery, here is jQuery code:

```
$("a").contextmenu(function() {
    this.href = "http://example.com";
});
```